# Embed form inside a block

Tags: forms, nodes

I am using a module (donate) that produces a form at a specific URL, for example, http://example.com/donate. I would like to put this form inside a block and display it on another page. Do you guys know the best way to do this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: For which version of Drupal are you interested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to 'donation' module and 'simple_paypal'
You can create a block with the content:

```
<?php
require_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'donation') .'/donation.module');
print donation_form();
?>
```

Make sure to set input format to PHP code

Comment: How would one do this with an existing node and you wanted to embed the add function. Say in Organic Groups embed the post form on the group page?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
print drupal_get_form('my_form'); //my_form is the function that returns the $form array
?>
```

Just put the above code in the block to display the respective form in a block. Any callback that returns HTML will work instead of `drupal_get_form()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work in your case but you can test [Blockify](http://drupal.org/project/blockify) module.

Comment: Solved. I used print drupal_get_form('form_id') to print the form in my page.tpl.php file