# Embedding a webform inside a node content

Tags: webforms

I need to embed a webform inside content, which is a node. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  The method I normally use it to make a custom [Panel](http://drupal.org/project/panels) page for my node.  The content area will contain the "node being viewed" as well as a custom block that renders out my form.

The easiest way, though, is to use the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module, and you can build your forms with the UI and easily attach them to a content type.

Comment: I would like to display the webform inside an html element of my content. What function must be used?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: This is for a 3 column page. First two columns contains some text and images, while on the third column, there must be a webform

Comment: @MPD Thanks, I got it working by using Panel module. I created a Custom Panel page, with the required layout. Then I added the webform's node id into one of the columns and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I think this function (embed webform in a node) is available in the latest Webform module.

Goto content > your-webform-node > edit > webform > form settings > advanced settings > available as block.

Comment: Thanx for explaining about block, but my problem has been to understand how to find "block name". Larzan answer explain it too.

Comment: I think this is the best vanilla solution, meaning no additional modules are required and no backend coding.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using the [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module mentioned by the others (i prefer that solution too) and want to **render the form manually in php** use this snippet:

```
$block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-370');
print render($block['content']);
```

with 370 being the node_id of your webform, the rest of the parameters don't have to be changed.

Comment: To find the node_id of the block just go to admin>content(>find content) and mouseover over the webform node.
node_id can be read on the bottom left corner of your browser, it's the last part of the url (www.yourdomain.com/node/node_id)

Answer (score 3):

To embed a webform inside content, you can create a [token](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/8.4.x) which can return a webform content programatically. Or create a block which can render a webform and place the block next or inside the content.

#### Drupal 8

Here is example how to render a webform:

```
$output = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('webform')->view($my_form);
```

You can also embed it as a block entity:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('myBlockID');
$block_content = \Drupal::entityManager()
   ->getViewBuilder('block')
   ->view($block);
```

Source: [How to embed a Webform?](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-embed-a-webform)

Comment: Thanks! But maybe consider using `entityTypeManager()` since [`entityManager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.2.x) is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly I think this module will be useful - [Webform Template](http://drupal.org/project/webform_template)

And using this patch from http://drupal.org/node/1430752(even for version 7.x-1.2) and following the few changes as mentioned in comment #4 you can even select a default template for each content type.

Hope this helps.