# Insert webform into content type field

Tags: 7, webforms

At the content type i add some field:

if you want to include or embed block into the body of your node 
https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block

if you want to include or embed view into the body of your node 
https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view

How about webform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding a webform inside a node content](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33397/embedding-a-webform-inside-a-node-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For webform: Use insert block module as well. 
Structure --> block --> Click configure one of the webform you want to add.--> look at the URL

Example: http://localhost/example.com/#overlay=admin/structure/block/manage/webform/client-block-5/configure

Type this "[block:webform=client-block-5]"

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with [Node Embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_embed) module

> Node Embed provides an input filter for CKEditor integration allowing a content editor the ability to embed the rendering of nodes within the body/fields of another node. This uses a View to allow for the browsing/preview/selection of a node to embed and provides a set of template suggestions that allow for the detailed control of node rendering when in embedded mode.