# Form is not being rendered in template file

Tags: forms, theming

I have tried drupal_render,drupal_get_form etc for rendering the form,but the form is not being rendered. Is there any error in code or else what else should i add to the code so that it works.

```
function questionnaire_template_form($form, &$form_state, $question) {
 print_r("in template function");

 $form_build = unserialize($question->criteria_data);

 foreach ($form_build as $key => $value) {

  $options = ($form_build[$key]['1']);
   $list = explode("\n", $options);

   $list = array_map('trim', $list);

   $list = array_filter($list, 'strlen');

   foreach ($list as $key => $value) {

    $new = explode('|',$value);
    $new_key = reset($new);
    $new_value = end($new);
    $new_list = array($new_key => $new_value);
    dsm($new_list);
   }
dsm('next');

   $fb = explode("_",$key);
   $type =reset($fb);

  if($type == 'radio') {

    if($form_build[$key]['0']) {
      $form['radio_form'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#options' => $list,
      );
    }
  }
   elseif($type == 'checkbox') {
    if($form_build[$key]['0']) {
     $form['checkbox_form'] = array(
       '#type' => 'checkboxes',
       '#options' => $list,
      );
    }
   }
   elseif($type == 'selectlist') {
    if($form_build[$key]['0']) {
      $form['selectlist_form'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $list,
        );
   }
  }

}
return $form;
}
```

Above code is my form.

```
<div>
<?php
//print_r($variables['entity']->qid);?></br><?php
print_r($variables['entity']->title);?></br><?php
print_r($variables['entity']->text);?></br><?php
?></br><?php
?></br><?php
if($variables['entity']->criteria) {
  ?><br/><?php
  $form_template = drupal_get_form('questionnaire_template_form' , $variables['entity']);
  print(drupal_render($form_template));

}
?></br><?php

print_r(l( t("Yes"), 'questionnaire/' . $variables['entity']->yes_quid));?></br><?php
print_r(l( t("No"), 'questionnaire/' . $variables['entity']->no_quid));?></br><?php

?>
</div>
```

And this is the template where I am rendering the form.
I am getting the form if I dsm the form

Comment: Why do you not creating custom module for the same?

Comment: This is custom module

Comment: I ma not seeing anywhere, did you miss printing the rendered form?

Comment: $form_template = drupal_get_form('questionnaire_template_form' , $variables['entity']);
  drupal_render($form_template);

Comment: Are you attaching form with menu item or displaying in block and are you creating template for form or custom template?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal render will return the html

```
drupal_render(drupal_get_form('form_id'));
```

you have to print the returned html as well.

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('form_id'));
```

in your case

```
$form_template = drupal_get_form('questionnaire_template_form' , $variables['entity']); 
drupal_render($form_template);
```

change it to

```
$form_template = drupal_get_form('questionnaire_template_form' , $variables['entity']); 
print drupal_render($form_template);
```

Comment: I updated the code in question.Tried with print drupal_render($form_template);      This too not working

Comment: different approach, check if this [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22815/best-way-to-render-a-form-on-a-node) helps you